# Printing data horizontally using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print data from the database in a horizontal manner.
I have two table one that holds products names and another that holds products performance by months eg  i want data to appear in a table like this
product name,performance by months from january to december
eg
product A,1000 ,2000, etc performance by months
product B,2000,3300, etc performace by months

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: Can you post your schema and sample data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to print data from mysql database in this format product name month and its performance each month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062069/i-want-to-print-data-from-mysql-database-in-this-format-product-name-month-and-i) --- Your question has been closed for a reason. Do not duplicate questions please! (so -1 from me).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I didn't realize you said you have *two* tables. So the query in my solution should be adapted with a `JOIN` and ordered, but we cannot dig further into this without knowing your schema. My solution addresses the main concern (i.e. printing results horizontally), provided you obtain two fields to show in two different *rows*.

---

Just retrieve your data and store it in a multidimensional array, THEN create the table.

```
$data = array();
$sql = "SELECT product, performance FROM table";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    $data[] = array($row['product'], $row['performance']);
}

echo "<table><tr>";

// print products in the first line of the table

foreach($data as $d)
{
   echo "<td>" . $d[0] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr><tr>";

// then print performances

foreach($data as $d)
{
   echo "<td>" . $d[1] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```